How to reference one Block in another before it is declared in Wagtail StreamField?
I am working on a Wagtail project where I have two custom blocks, TextNode and AnswerNode, both inheriting from a base Node class. I need to reference TextNode inside AnswerNode and vice versa. However, I am encountering a circular dependency issue because TextNode is not defined when it is referenced in AnswerNode.
Here is the relevant part of my models.py:
from wagtail.core import blocks
from django.db import models
import uuid

class Node(blocks.StructBlock):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        editable=False,
        default=uuid.uuid4
    )

class AnswerNode(Node):
    text = blocks.CharBlock(max_length=255)
    type = blocks.ChoiceBlock(
        choices=AnswerType.choices,
        default=AnswerType.DIALOGUE
    )
    next = blocks.StreamBlock([("TextNode", TextNode())])

class TextNode(Node):
    text = blocks.RichTextBlock()

    answers = blocks.StreamBlock(
        [("AnswerNode", AnswerNode())]
    )

I've tried adding __init__ method to AnswerNode, but I encounter RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded exception.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Since this got closed, I posted a possible solution over on the linked discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833593/how-to-solve-wagtail-cyclic-block-dependency-when-using-a-streamblock/79186839#79186839
